# Android's WebKit and JavaServerFaces

Tags: android, jsf, webkit

I wonder why WebKit trying to render my page as XML instead of HTML..
I tried this issue (via emulator and real device) for all available Android SDK versions and all OK only since Android 2.3.4 (API 10) with WebKit/533.1
One more strange thing is browser versions:

Android 2.2.1 has WebKit/533.1 and Android 2.3.4 also has WebKit/533.1

So, my page does not want to render in 2.2.1 with 533.1, but all good in 2.3.4 with the same 533.1??
Page code is simple:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache" />
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

Google says I must declare Content-Type header as text/html, but it has been already declared. What I can see with LiveHTTPHeaders (Firefox add-on) while requesting that JSF page:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.0 JSP/2.2 (GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.1 Java/Sun Microsystems Inc./1.6), JSF/2.0
Server: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.1
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 1559
Date: Tue, 13 Mar 2012 19:50:13 GMT
```

Did you meet such kinds of issues?

Thanks,
Vladimir

Comment: Sure that you don't have `<?xml ... ?>` in top of page? Sure that the request URL matches `FacesServlet`?

Comment: yes, I dont have <?xml ... ?> and reques works with FacesServlet..

Comment: What is the source code which Android retrieves? Is it the generated HTML output? Or is it the unparsed raw JSF source code?

Comment: sorry, but I cant to realize how to look at src code in emulator or in device browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. Just remove `<ui:composition>` tag from inside body.

Comment: That tag is a templating tag, you should not have used it in the body of a single non-templated view at all. Any content outside `<ui:composition>` is disregarded and the template file as definied in `template` attribute would be used. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792862/how-to-include-another-xhtml-in-xhtml-using-jsf-2-0-facelets/4793959#4793959